# Change colour on GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

```
public ATMgui1() 
{
    setTitle("ATM Transactions");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

    contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setOpaque(false);

    JLabel pinLabel = new JLabel("Enter your Pin:");
    pinLabel.setOpaque(false);
    pinTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton pinButton = new JButton( "EnterPin OK");
    pinButton.setOpaque(false);

    JLabel pinChangeLabel = new JLabel("Enter your new Pin:");
    JTextField pinChangeTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton pinChangeButton = new JButton( "Change Pin");

    JButton exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");
    exitButton.addActionListener(e -> this.dispose());

    pinButton.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel pinPanel = new JPanel();
    pinPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    pinPanel.add(pinLabel);
    pinPanel.add(pinTextField);
    pinPanel.add(pinButton);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeLabel);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeTextField);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeButton);

    pinPanel.add(exitButton);

    contentPane.add(pinPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I tried changing the background but it's not completely changing, the code is kinda all over the place and I think it's only in one section that's actually what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Also, the image you tried to share is only on your computer, so it can't be viewed by others...

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] so we can see why your code is not working. Please help us help you.

Comment: @JohnD: css really doesn't have a place in this.

Comment: My guess: you've got components placed on top of the contentPane, and you've not made them non-opaque. Call `setOpaque(false)` on the key ones that are covering the color.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter ok, thanks, i'll try that!

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter i changed it and added more code but now theres no colour at all

Comment: Again, don't make contentPane non-opaque. Get rid of `contentPane.setOpaque(false)`. Please do read in the API what opaque means and why this matters. It means that you can't see through the component.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing:

[image]

The JPanel that hold your components, your JTextFields, labels and buttons should be made non-opaque. Call `.setOpaque(false)` on it, and you should see the color underneath it.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PinkBackground {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            panel.add(new JTextField(10));
            panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
            panel.add(new JTextField(10));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));

            // panel.setOpaque(false);  // ******* uncomment this! **********

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Make your pinPanel non-opaque. The contentPane, the component that you're setting to pink should remain opaque:

```
public ATMgui1() {

    setTitle("ATM Transactions");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

    contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JLabel pinLabel = new JLabel("Enter your Pin:");
    // pinLabel.setOpaque(false);
    pinTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton pinButton = new JButton("EnterPin OK");
    // pinButton.setOpaque(false);

    JLabel pinChangeLabel = new JLabel("Enter your new Pin:");
    JTextField pinChangeTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton pinChangeButton = new JButton("Change Pin");

    JButton exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");
    exitButton.addActionListener(e -> this.dispose());

    pinButton.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel pinPanel = new JPanel();
    pinPanel.setOpaque(false); // !!
    pinPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    pinPanel.add(pinLabel);
    pinPanel.add(pinTextField);
    pinPanel.add(pinButton);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeLabel);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeTextField);
    pinPanel.add(pinChangeButton);

    pinPanel.add(exitButton);

    contentPane.add(pinPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: i tried:        JLabel pinLabel = new JLabel("Enter your Pin:");
        pinLabel.setOpaque(false);
        pinTextField = new JTextField();
        JButton pinButton = new JButton( "EnterPin OK");
        pinButton.setOpaque(false);                       it's not doing anything

Comment: @LiyanA: no, that's not what I'm telling you to do. Rather the JPanel that holds them all. And we've asked for your [mcve] code, but you've yet to show it to us, so no one can tell you what you're doing wrong. Please fix. For an example of MCVE, please see my code posted above.

Comment: @LiyanA: make your pinPanel non-opaque, not the contentPane.